# Write a loop invariant for partial correctness of Hoare Triple

Tags: logic, loop-invariant, hoare-logic

I am new to the world of logic. I am learning Hoare Logic and Partial & Total correctness of programs. I tried alot to solve the below question but failed.

```
Write a loop invariant P to show partial correctness for the Hoare triple

{x = ¬x ∧ y = ¬y ∧ x >= 0} mult {z = ¬x * ¬y}

where mult is the following program that computes the product of x and y and stores it in z:

   mult: 
      z := 0;
      while (y > 0) do
      z := z + x;
      y := y - 1;
```

One of my friend gave me the following answer but I don't know if it correct or not.

```
Invariant P is (¬x * ¬y = z + ¬x * y) ∧ x = ¬x. Intuitively, z holds the part of the result that is already computed, and (¬x * y) is what remains to compute.
```

Please teach me step by step of how to solve this question.

Comment: could you explain what the symbol "¬y" means?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the triple should read `{x = x₀ ∧ y = y₀ ∧ x >= 0} mult {z = x₀ * y₀}`